# Connecting a digital tachometer (RPM-meter) to an EC-fan

Tags: fan, tachometer

I have an EC-ventilator with 4 output contacts:

1. +10 V
2. 0-10 V
3. GND
4. TACH (2 pulses per revolution)

The first three contacts are for speed control with a 10 kΩ potentiometer. I have succesfully connected it. Now I want to buy a digital tachometer and connect it to the TACH output.

1. What tachometer should I use?
2. Which of the contacts in addition to TACH should I use to connect the tachometer to my fan?

I had found a [0-10 V tachometer](https://aliexpress.ru/item/1005004584726379.html?sku_id=12000029721604101), but I am not sure about it. There aren't any examples of circuit connections anywhere.

Comment: What would be the further processing of the tachometer value?

Comment: Most off all, It will be the silmple visual analys for precision manual speed tuning. (This speed are absolutly equal to productivity of ventilation unlike the voltage on the potentiometer (or the position of potentiometer), so it is important indicator) Also it allow to control pollution on filter for a months. Of course a low alarm relay would not be useless but it is not priority task.

Comment: So you just need a frequency counter with 30 s scan interval to read RPMs.

Comment: Yes, I need to connect such a counter to TACH contact for counting RPM. But how will I do that, and what exactly counter do I need? I came across counters with Hall sensor, I came across counters with Hz sensor, they are not right

Comment: An Arduino with a display add on board could do this. I don't think there are ready made counter modules with this scan rate.

Comment: An automotive tacho for 4 cylinder engines would work probably work.

Answer (score 0):

Which connections:

Tach and Ground

Some supply voltage to run the tachometer

Possibly a pull-up reiustor on the tach line if needed.

The device in your link appaers to be some sort of voltmeter, not a pulse counting tachometer. try this one instead.

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32995622495.html

set it to 1000rpm=33.33Hz